# Jacobson-Bourbaki correspondence

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

The Jacobson-Bourbaki correspondence induces the traditional, finite Galois correspondence by suitable restriction; I've been pondering two things: 1. Are there any (other) interesting applications of this correspondence known ? (It only seems to lead an existence as an exercise in algebra textbooks, and never appears in lectures.) 2. Does there exist an infinite(-dimensional) version, exploiting something akin to the Krull topology ?
Thanks in advance for any helpful remarks or insights ! Kind regards, Stephan.

Comment: If you can access MathSciNet, you might get some clues from a simple 'Anywhere' search of their database for 'Jacobson-Bourbaki'.   This returns 31 items, ranging from a paper by Henri Cartan (1947) to one by Lars Kadison (2008).   Of course, that kind of search doesn't get into the texts of articles.   My point (as a non-specialist) is that further developments of mathematical ideas almost always occur; but whether they are 'interesting' is another question.  

Comment: (No, I'm afraid I can't get into MathSciNet.) Hopefully nobody misunderstands the intention of my question; I most certainly did not want to detract from the merit of the Jacobson-Bourbaki correspondence as such, quite the contrary ! I just find it a pity that such a fine instrument is left in the toolkit unused (seemingly) ... Kind regrads, Stephan.

Comment: What is the Jacobson-Bourbaki correspondence?

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan: probably easiest if I just give you this link:
http://eom.springer.de/J/j110010.htm

Kind regards, Stephan.